# Magento Tag Url-Rewrite?

Tags: zend-framework, magento, url-rewriting, tags

I am trying to make a permanent url rewrite for tags in Magento.

Unfortunately with url-rewrite it won't work.

The path to the tag is:

```
magento/tag/product/list/tagId/1/
```

I want to make a url rewrite to:

```
magento/tag/bathroom
```

Where do I have to make changes to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us what's the rule that you're using with the url rewrites? It should be a custom url rewrite with the following fields:

ID Path: whatever

Request Path: /tag/product/list/tagId/1/

Target Path: /tag/bathroom

Redirect: yes (301)

The path /tag/product/list/tagId/1/ is working, isn't it?

Comment: yes, both paths are working fine.
but i want the tag itself to be replaced, e.g. that the path of the tag is replace in the tag-cloud and in the product page

Comment: OK, I see. I've looking for something similar (for free) and haven't found anything :(. Maybe this extension: http://www.mageworx.com/seo-suite-pro-magento-extension.html

Comment: I haven't found a way to use the rewritten URL from within the tag cloud either, aside from paid SEO extensions.